# how to display the value in the spring textarea

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

This is my code.The text area doesn't display the value. It only displays the empty text area.
There is value in the databse table.

```
<form:textarea path="groupDescription" placeholder="Description:"    
value="${roleGroupObject.groupDescription}" />
```

Comment: The value is provided by the attribute groupDescription. In your controller, you should set it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check in the console whether you're getting the value from database or not.

Secondly, placeholder sometimes doesn't work in Internet Explorer or Firefox. Try to check in other browser(like Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

try

${roleGroupObject.groupDescription}

It usually works like this for me.

give your value here